# Copy contents of all files into one file in bash different sequence

Tags: bash, cat

I need to combine all files in a folder to a single file.
Files are named as `t1, t2, t3, ..., t1500` and output file is "`all`".

I've used the following command in `bash`: `cat t* >> all`
but it combines files in the sequence `t1, t10, t11, ...` instead of `t1, t2, t3, ...`
Any help please.

Comment: sort them first : man sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
cat t{1..1500} > all
```

If you get any error involving a too-long command line, you can try

```
for i in {1..1500}; do
  echo "t$i"
done | xargs -n 1500 cat
```

A longer, but arguably more readable, method that manually splits the list up between multiple calls to `cat`:

```
{ cat t{1..100}
  cat t{101..500}    
  cat t{601..1000}
  cat t{1001..1500}
} > all
```

Comment: +1 you have a very annoying habit of providing a superior solution :-)

Comment: @Jord That's because I made a very stupid typo :) `t$1` should be `t$i`; thanks for catching that, and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Mine:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*t[[:digit:]]+$' | sort -V | xargs cat > all
```

Or

```
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\n" t+([[:digit:]]) | sort -V | xargs cat > all
```

Or perhaps simply (if applicable):

```
printf "%s\n" t* | sort -V | xargs cat > all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in {1..1500}; do cat t${i} >> all; done
```

Read more about brace-expansion in bash [man-page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)

Comment: One drawback is that this requires spawning 1500 separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are looking for a sequence t1 t10 t11 then

following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls -1 t*)
do
  cat $file >> all
done
```

`ls` by default list in the required order.